# MYSQL LEFT JOIN no id has been returned

Tags: php, mysql, join

I am trying to join 2 tables called `ads` and `images`

`ads`

```
ad_id       int(11)              
title       varchar(200)         
price       int(10)              
description text             
city        varchar(20)              
location    varchar(50)              
date        datetime
```

`images`

```
img_id  int(11)              
ad_id   int(11)              
images  varchar(100)         
session varchar(32)
```

Here is my code when I try to join tables and get all info from the ads table and get info from images table if it's any uploaded.

```
 SELECT *
    FROM ads
    LEFT OUTER JOIN images
    ON images.ad_id = ads.ad_id 
    GROUP BY ads.ad_id DESC
```

The problem I am having is that if there are no images for the ads, then the post is still returned without an image (which is thats what I want), **but it doesnt return an ad_id.** and therefore I cant locate the post without an ad_id. Where I am missing a point here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to change your `SELECT` statement to this.

```
SELECT ads.*, images.img_id, images.images, images.session
    FROM ads
    LEFT JOIN images
    ON images.ad_id = ads.ad_id 
    GROUP BY ads.ad_id DESC
```

I would also recommend to implicitly define what you want from the ads table as it will speed up your select.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you sir! Btw, I need to select * from ads as I use all of the info from the table :)

Comment: @StuckBetweenTrees your query will be faster if you list them out instead of using `*` as using the `*` requires extra processing to determine the columns to select